# Needing Help creating ADOrganizationalUnits

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm Having trouble creating new ADOrganizationalUnits and ADGroups. It needs to be done in Powershell, but I'm just not grasping the concept for some reason. Here's my  code:

I've looked through the documentation but I still can't figure it out.

```bsh
# Script to create New AD Org. Units
#Author : Phil Bauer

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$oupath = "OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
$oupathIT = "OU=IT,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
$oupathSales = "OU=Sales,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
$oupathDesign = "OU=Design,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
$oupathMark = "OU=Marketing,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
$oupathProd = "OU=Production,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
New-ADGroup -Name: "HelpDesk" -DisplayName: "Help Desk" -path: "OU=Business , DC=PhilB , DC=local"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "Sales" -path: $oupath
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "Design" -path: $oupath
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "Marketing" -path: $oupath
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "Production" -path: $oupath
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "IT" -path: $oupath
New-ADGroup -Name: "SalesIT" -DisplayName: "Sales IT" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathIT -
New-ADGroup -Name: "DisplayIT" -DisplayName: "Design IT" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathIT
New-ADGroup -Name: "MkgtIT" -DisplayName: "Marketing IT" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathIT
New-ADGroup -Name: "DsgnIT" -DisplayName: "Production IT" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathIT
New-ADGroup -Name: "SalesMgr" -DisplayName: "Sales Manager" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathSales
New-ADGroup -Name: "SalesField"-DisplayName: "Field Sales" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathSales
New-ADGroup -Name: "DsgnMgr" -DisplayName:  "Design Manager " -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path: $oupathDesign
New-ADGroup -Name: "Dsgn" -DisplayName: "Designers" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path $oupathDesign
New-ADGroup -Name:"MktHead" -DisplayName: "Lead Marketer" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path $oupathMark
New-ADGroup -Name: "MktJr" -DisplayName: "Marketing Juniors" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path $oupathMark
New-ADGroup -Name: "ProdMgr" -DisplayName: "Production Manager" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path $oupathProd
New-ADGroup -Name: "ProdTeam" -DisplayName: "Production Team" -GroupCategory: "Security" -GroupScope: "Global" -path $oupathProd
```

The error message I've been getting is like this:

```bsh
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : The server is unwilling to process the request
At line:13 char:1
+ New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name: "Sales" -path: $oupath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Sales,OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local:String) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit]
   , ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationa
   lUnit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to provide colon (:) with the AD PowerShell cmdlets' properties, as shown in the official docs of these cmdlets, the link of which is provided below.

- (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adgroup?view=win10-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adorganizationalunit?view=win10-ps)

White space (blank) characters may be present on either side of the comma in DC, but I don't recommend it. (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.glpa200/tivdnm.htm)

So, you should rewrite the script as suggested below:

```
New-ADGroup -Name "HelpDesk" -DisplayName "Help Desk" -path "OU=Business,DC=PhilB,DC=local"
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Sales" -path $oupath
...
```